# How to drop duplicate rows based on another column condition?

Tags: r, duplicates

How can I select the duplicated row (only based on first column) based on the max in the second column:

```
data<-data.frame(a=c(1,3,3,3),b=c(1,4,6,3),d=c(1,5,7,1))

a b d
1 1 1
3 4 5
3 6 7
3 3 1


a b d
1 1 1
3 6 7
```

In the second column 6 is max between *4,6,3*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like the following, using "dplyr":

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%                  ## Your data
  group_by(a) %>%         ##   grouped by "a"
  filter(b == max(b))     ##   filtered to only include the rows where b == max(b)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: a
# 
#   a b d
# 1 1 1 1
# 2 3 6 7
```

Note, however, that if there are more rows that match `b == max(b)` those would also be returned. Thus, an alternative might be:

```
data %>%                  ## Your data
  group_by(a) %>%         ##   grouped by "a"
  arrange(desc(b)) %>%    ##   sorted by descending values of "b"
  slice(1)                ##   with just the first row extracted
```

Comment: Thanks, what `%>%` do exactly?

Comment: @Soheil, it "pipes" the output from one step to the next and allows you to construct a "statement" (like my comments) about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Options using `data.table` are

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .SD[which.max(b)], a]
#   a b d
#1: 1 1 1
#2: 3 6 7
```

Or using `.I` to get the row index (which would be a bit faster)

```
 setDT(data)[data[, .I[which.max(b)], a]$V1]
 #   a b d
 #1: 1 1 1
 #2: 3 6 7
```

Or

```
setkey(setDT(data), a,b)[,.SD[.N], a]
#   a b d
#1: 1 1 1
#2: 3 6 7
```

If there are ties for the maximum values

```
setDT(data)[, .SD[max(b)==b], a]
#   a b d
#1: 1 1 1
#2: 3 6 7
```